# Memory leak for static declaration of context and INSTANCE , how do I alter it?

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, android-context, android-memory

Currently in my codebase I have the following class(part of it) where it shows me 2 memory leaks with the message " Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to Myclass which has field context pointing to Context); this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)" 
I am not sure what the alternative is. Is this a 100% memory leak ? I get the leak warning on  "INSTANCE;" and "static" declaration for context. Any idea how to go about fixing it?

```
public enum Myclass {
        INSTANCE;

    public static final boolean TLS_ENABLED = true;
    private static final String TAG = Myclass.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String SP = "My_class";


    private static Context context;
       public void init(Context context, String appKey, String appSecret) {
        init(context, null, appKey, appSecret);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize class
     *
     * @param context   Application level context.
     * @param apiUrl    API url of backend server
     * @param appKey    Application key
     * @param appSecret Application secret
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If activity instance will be passed as the context
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If application key is empty or null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If application secret is empty or null
     */
    public void init(Context context, String apiUrl, String appKey, String appSecret) {
        if (null == context) { throw new NullPointerException(); }

        if (!(context instanceof Application)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Supply my class with application context"); }

//        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(apiUrl)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Api url can't be null or empty string"); }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(appKey)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("App key can't be null or empty string"); }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(appSecret)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("App secret can't be null or empty string"); }

        this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
        this.appKey = appKey;
        this.appSecret = appSecret;
        this.sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SP, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        MyClass.context = context;
        initManagers();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes managers. This method must be called after constructor
     * returns, as the managers during own initialization may use myclass.get()
     * method.
     */
    private void initManagers() {
        accountManager = new AccountManager();
        myclassApi = new MyclassApi(context, apiUrl);
        contactManager = new ContactManager();
        connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
        meetingListManager = new MeetingListManager();
    }


    /**
     * Returns {@link Context} that was passed to
     * {@link myclass#init(Context, String, String)}.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    /**
     * Returns {@link SharedPreferences} instance.
     *
     * @return SharedPreferences
     */
    public SharedPreferences getSp() {
        return this.sp;
    }


       public static class Event<T> {
        private State state = State.SUCCESS;
        private Throwable t;
        private T data;
        private String errorMessage;

        /**
         * Event state. If event related to network request/response
         * operations - state indicates the physical (not logical)
         * success or fail of request.
         */
        public enum State {
            /**
             * Indicates that attempt to get data or perform task successful
             */
            SUCCESS,
            /**
             * Indicates that attempt to get data or perform task fails,
             * and reason of fail is the incorrect request data
             */
            FAIL,
            /**
             * Indicates that attempt to get data or perform task encounter an error
             * mostly due to connection problem
             */
            ERROR,
            /**
             * Indicates that attempt to get data or perform task was ignored
             * according to internal state of event producer.
             */
            IGNORED
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *safe* to store application context in a static field, you can simple call `context.getApplicationContext()` on any context reference you get before storing it in a static field.

The application context is a singleton anyway and you cannot leak it.

Comment: so you mean to say I should use it here:  public static Context getContext() {
        return context.getApplicationcontext();
    }    ? Also, it shows me INSTANCE is causing memory leak as a warning when I inspect code, is that just an empty warning without a base?

Comment: in your init method, set your context = context.getApplicationContext()

Comment: sounds good thanks! But when I run inspect code, it still shows INSTANCE and context causes memory leak warning. Can that be ignored?

Comment: You can just suppress that, IDE can't differentiate application context from non application context, as long as you are only storing application context, you can ignore/suppressing the warning

Comment: **Celebrations**

Answer (score 1):

This seems like warning from IDE if you are making sure that context will store only ApplicationContext, not Activity context you can suppress this warning using annotation.

`@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")`

If you want to understand more about memory leaks you can check my only blog :) [here](https://medium.com/@akhilgupta.me/memory-leaks-in-android-fe4f5b97fa5e)